# "On that note" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I was wondering if anyone knew what the equivalent of "on that note" in Japanese would be.

Comment: Hi! I'm actually quite curious to hear some natives speakers answer this question, but our rules here at the Japanese Language Stack Exchange say that a question must include at least some evidence of prior research effort. Could you describe some phrases you think might correspond, or talk about places you have looked for an equivalent phrase?

Answer (score 2):

I am *not* a native speaker, but I think I have a word that will work in this case.

In English, "on that note" essentially means "let's end there," or even "well then."  It is a phrase that you use to essentially close a topic of conversation, table it for later, or to create an opening to physically leave if needed.

In my Japanese experience, a lot of people will accomplish what I listed with the simple phrase [それでは](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF), which is often shortened to [では](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF) in informal circumstances.  The translation listed on jisho.org is `well; then; well then; in that case` and I feel that those are good translations.  But it doesn't really capture the context in which it is used.  Simply, it provides a final thought for the conversation (one that you are just confirming got finished), allowing you to potentially table that topic of conversation for later.  It also provides an opportunity to end the conversation and physically leave if necessary.

So while not a perfect fit, I would say that それでは, or it's shortened form では provide a reasonable fit for what you are trying to accomplish with 'on that note.'

<sub>Here's two more sources on the meaning of [では](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF.html) and [それでは](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF.html).</sub>